# how to replace text "column_name" from file1.txt with whole content of file2.txt

Tags: linux, unix

how to replace text "column_name" from file1.txt with whole content of file2.txt

file1.txt:-

```
insert into owner.table_name select **column_name**
```

file2.txt:-

```
DB_ID,
trim(DB_NAME),
DB_TYPE,
trim(HOST_NAME),
trim(STANDY_HOST_NAME),
trim(GG_HOST_NAME),
trim(CONTACT_PERSON),
EXEMPT,
TYPE,
trim(STREAM),
RAC,
trim(INFORMATION),
trim(EMAIL)
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141387/sed-replace-string-with-file-contents

Comment: Please show the expected output. Does `file1.txt` contain `**` or is this an attempt to display `column_name` in bold? Please [edit] your question to answer.